# How can I pass the "isActive" prop from NavLink to its children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

```
function NavigationLink({ to, title, exactPath, Icon }) {
  const resolved = useResolvedPath(to);
  const match = useMatch({
    path: resolved.pathname,
    end: exactPath,
  });
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <StyledNavLink linkSelected={match}>
      <NavLink
        to={to}
        style={({ isActive }) =>
          isActive ? setActive(true) : setActive(false)
        }
      >
        <Title>{title}</Title>
        <SelectedContainerIcon active={active}>
          <Icon />
        </SelectedContainerIcon>
      </NavLink>
    </StyledNavLink>
  );
}
```

Right now I am using this, using the "isActive" to change a state that is then passed to the child component (to change the icon's background color) but it is giving me a rendering error (despite actually working well). Is there a way to pass the "isActive" directly to the child?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to taking a function callback for the `className` and `style` prop, the `NavLink` also takes a render function as the `children` prop.

Don't use the `className` or `style` props to issue side-effects like enqueueing state updates.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#navlink)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

Your code:

```
function NavigationLink({ to, title, exactPath, Icon }) {
  const resolved = useResolvedPath(to);
  const match = useMatch({
    path: resolved.pathname,
    end: exactPath,
  });

  return (
    <StyledNavLink linkSelected={match}>
      <NavLink to={to}>
        {({ isActive }) => (
          <>
            <Title>{title}</Title>
            <SelectedContainerIcon active={isActive}>
              <Icon />
            </SelectedContainerIcon>
          </>
        )}
      </NavLink>
    </StyledNavLink>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically render a `className` based on the `isActive` property, instead of the `style` attribute, and use CSS descendent selectors to change children of the active class.

```js
<NavLink 
  to={to} 
  className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? "active" : "" }
>
  <Title>{title}</Title>
  <SelectedContainerIcon>
    <Icon />
  </SelectedContainerIcon>
</NavLink>
```

```css
.active i {
  background-color: blue
}
```

With this solution it probably won't be necessary to save the `active` status to state. CSS will do the logic for you.

Comment: OP is trying to pass an `active` prop based on the `isActive` state of the `NavLink` to the child `SelectedContainerIcon` component.

Comment: I was keying off of the "to change the icon's background color" part, wherein I didn't think it was necessary to pass the prop.

Comment: Yup, no worries, was just pointing out what I found to be a bit of a discrepancy. I think using a CSS selector to target nested `i` elements could possibly work, if that is what is actually rendered.